# Language switcher lag

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, language

When I am changing the language layout (English <-> Bulgarian) most of the times I have huge lag or even buggy behavior. The language indicator says one thing, but when I type it is in the other language. 
This actually happens on every OSX version I've used the last years (Mountain Lion - Sierra).
Here is a gif of the problem:

[image]

Now I'm totally pissed off and I cannot stand it anymore. Any clues of how to fix it?

Comment: Interesting you say you have had this for a long time.  I have seen various complaints about it in Sierra, but not earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SIRI on?  If so, try turning it off and restarting.

Just in case somebody has the same issue but wants to continue using Siri:
make sure your keyboard shortcut for Siri doesn't conflict with the keyboard switch combination.

Original text:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7769867?start=0&tstart=0